# Gstreamer: moov-recovery info with qtmux?

Tags: gstreamer, mp4, recover

I am trying to experiment with Gstreamer and moov-recovery via qtmux.

When I try to get the recovery moov from a non-corrupted .mp4 file

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=full.mp4 ! qtdemux ! qtmux moov-recovery-file=moov_recov.mrf ! filesink location=recovered_video.mp4
```

then I get

```
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is PREROLLING ...
Pipeline is PREROLLED ...
Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
New clock: GstSystemClock
Got EOS from element "pipeline0".
Execution ended after 0:00:00.112361582
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Setting pipeline to READY ...
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ...
```

What is the reason for the `Got EOS from element "pipeline0"`?

And what would be the correct way to pull the recovery moov from the .mp4 file?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your muxing process was a success. It took about a tenth of a second. Therefore the EOS. Since it did not crash or anything the file probaly gets removed after a successful muxing. There is no point in keeping that file.

Comment: I did not realitet that it ended successfully. I thought it crashed 0.1sec into to video clip. 
The output file exists thank you for making me realise that.